# Android devices are not showing up in xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022

There was a problem recently. In studio 2019, 2022, the xamarin project for android works every other time. Android devices both emulator and physical device are not displayed. I've tried deleting bin and obj files. But a complete reinstallation of the studio helped. After the project is closed, the situation repeats itself.

The same project in two different environments.
[image]

The project is absolutely pure xamarin. Reload adb is disabled in menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report the issue as following shows:
[image]